# Have an efficiency issue. Need to pass data between classes

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, bitmap

So I have a Gridview and and ImageAdapter class. The images all get grab from a folder and then populated into the grid view. I then have another class that displays the full image when clicked. However whenever someone clicks an image ImageAdapter has to get called again and all the images need to be repopulated into my variables and then I just pick out the one I need. This is terribly inefficient but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Here is my code.

Main Classes (favorites in this case) with the grid view

```
public class Favorites extends Activity {    

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.favgridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v, int position, long id){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }       
    }); 
}   
}
```

My ImageAdapter class, you can see that I load all the images as bitmaps into an array.

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private Bitmap[]mis_fotos;

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount(){
    get_images();
    return mis_fotos.length;
}

public Bitmap getItem(int position){
    get_images();
    return mis_fotos[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);   
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }   

    imageView.setImageBitmap(mis_fotos[position]);
    return imageView;
}


private void get_images(){

    String dirPath = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "favorites";

    File directory = new File(dirPath);

    File[] archivos = directory.listFiles();
    mis_fotos = new Bitmap[archivos.length];

    for (int cont=0; cont<archivos.length;cont++){
        File imgFile = new File(archivos[cont].toString());
        mis_fotos[cont] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

 }
```

And Finally my Full Image Class

```
 public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.getItem(position));   
}

 }
```

So you can see that when I use the full image all I can pass is the position integer from the gridview class. I then have to call get_images() again in the ImageAdapter class and repopulate an array all over again.

All I need to to pass a single image from the gridview to the fullimage class when an image is clicked. I know there is an easier and far more efficient way to do this. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work around required, you are calling `get_images()` multiple times inside an Adapter class which is a bad way. Better solution is remove it from Adapter class and keep inside the MainActivity and just call it before setting the Adapter like,

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
get_images();
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

And then your method for Adapter class should be like,

```
public int getCount() {
   return mis_fotos.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mis_fotos[position];
}
```

Now, I come to your issue that is you want to show an Image as fullscreen to Next Activity. So, why don't you fetch the Bitmap from clicked ListView Item and pass it to Next Activity?. So, how can you do that? Here it is,

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
      i.putExtras(bundle);
      startActivity(i);
});
```

So, nothing tricky, just getting the Bitmap using `getItem(position);` and the sending it to Next Activity using Bundle. Now you can easily get the Bitmap using

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("bitmap");
// create new Bitmap with any height, width required by you.
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);
```

and show to ImageView.

Comment: Thanks! The `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);` piece of code did the magic for me. Was what I needed. Now that I could access that class it opens up all kinds of possibilities. I got it working but I changed up my code a bit. I didn't load and array of bitmaps but instead an array of filenames, and then I just set the images based on the filename and pass the filename between activities. Got it working good now I think. Thanks for the help!